# CAShapeLayer missing pixel in top-left corner

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, swift3

I'm using a `CAShapeLayer` with a `UIBezierPath` to draw a bordered box in a view.

This is working fine, but the very first pixel (top, left) is not drawn.

This is my code:

```
let focusSize = CGRect(x: focusX, y: focusY, width: focusWidth, height: focusHeight)
let focusPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: focusSize, cornerRadius: 0)

let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.path = focusPath.cgPath
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
borderLayer.frame = self.someView.bounds
self.someView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

The result (note the pixel in the top, left corner):

[image: Weird pixel]

I thought this might be related to antialiasing, but playing around with the x, y and borderWidth does not seem to fix the issue.
Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Did you try to bring your layer to the front? Did you try to print out the all sublayers of your `someView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason when you create a path using `(roundedRect rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat)` it is not closed (despite what it says in the documentation).

Calling `focusPath.close()` closes the path and removes the missing pixel.

However, if you don't want rounded corners just use a normal rect and it will draw correctly.

`let focusPath = UIBezierPath(rect: focusSize)`

For anyone interested here are the resulting paths:

```
UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 0)
<UIBezierPath: 0x6180000b8000; <MoveTo {10, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 110}>,
 <LineTo {10, 110}>,
 <LineTo {10, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10, 10}>

//After calling path.close()
<UIBezierPath: 0x6180000b8000; <MoveTo {10, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 110}>,
 <LineTo {10, 110}>,
 <LineTo {10, 10}>,
 <LineTo {10, 10}>,
 <Close>

 UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
<UIBezierPath: 0x6180000b7f40; <MoveTo {10, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 10}>,
 <LineTo {110, 110}>,
 <LineTo {10, 110}>,
 <Close>
```

Setting the `lineCap` may make the box appear correctly, but isn't fixing the issue as it just extends the visible end points and covers up the missing bit. Set `borderLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel` to see why this can be a problem.

Comment: It should result in a rectangle according to the apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624356-init

Comment: It should, but it doesn't. Try it.

Comment: To the people down voting this answer; Try it first! It's correct

Comment: This seems to be the best answer in my context. I have no intention to drawing corner radius, so using UIBezierPath(rect) fits my case best. Thank you

Comment: I have just tried that. The path is composed from a move to point, 3 lines and a close subpath element. Therefore you answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Sulthan, are you sure you were testing with `roundedRect`, and not just `rect`?

Comment: @JamesP My apologies. I was printing the beziers in one of my older projects and the bezier was actually created from `CGMutablePath.addRoundedRect` which seems to be working quite differently. The path seems to be closed though - not using an explicit close but using a line.

Comment: @Sulthan That's the problem, it means the line has ends so the `lineCap` comes into play, if it was properly closed it would have no end and no visible join. I doubt anyone ever noticed as if the cornerRadius was anything other than 0 you'd never be able to tell. Probably time for a bug report...

Comment: @JamesP So would you say this is a bug? I might just create a bug report for it.

Comment: @Rob I think it is, or at least it doesn't match the documentation.

Comment: The problem is not in the path but in the shape layer. Specifically in the property lineCap. This code works, but it is giving wrong informations. This is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719997/1754559

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza That's not true. If the path was properly closed then the lineCap would have no effect. Changing the lineCap is only covering up the real problem.

Comment: Try in a playground please. You will see that by adding the correct lineCap it will work properly.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza It may look correct, but it hasn't solved the underlying issue. Try the same thing with an unclosed triangle path.

Comment: The documentation states "This method creates a closed subpath, proceeding in a clockwise direction (relative to the default coordinate system) as it creates the necessary line and curve segments." and it is in fact closed. The last point is as expected a line to the starting point.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Look at the logs in my answer, the path is not closed, **the documentation is wrong**. From the docs:  "A closed subpath treats the starting point as a junction between connected line segments; the starting point is rendered using the selected line-join method. In contrast, if you close the path by adding a line segment that connects to the starting point, both ends of the path are drawn using the selected line-cap method." If it was a closed subpath then the lineCap would not be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing a missing pixel on your rect is because you haven't configured the `lineCap` property correctly.

Try adding this line :

```
borderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare
```

For more on line cap (and line join which is also important to understand) see this page : http://calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/22/cashapelayer-in-depth.html#line-cap

Comment: This definitely shows the border correctly, but if the roundedRect method created a closed path like it is supposed to then the lineCap would have no effect.

Comment: You're right. I almost suggested to use `close()` on the path but then saw that the documentation said the path was closed. I found it weird and suggested this instead. Documentation is wrong, that's the real answer...

Answer (score 2):

Yes as per the doc it should be a rect but I dont think it mentions the lineWidth

This seems to be the reason why you see a pixel missing

```
borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
```

Now when you change the width to 1 then it draws a perfect rectangle without any missing pixels

Changing the lineWidth to 10 shows considerable difference in the gap

The solution to your problem would be using this

```
borderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare
```

Check these [lineCap](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521905-linecap) & [Line Cap Values](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer/line_cap_values)

Comment: That is interesting, I would expect no border radius to be drawn if the value is set to 0.